# Overcome List View Threshold with OR filter?

Tags: 2010, filter, list-view-threshold

I have a list that multiple different people of different roles have to use. There are "submitters", "targets" and "managers" (specifically called "Created By", "Assigned To" and "DM", erspectively, in the list).

My goal was to have a single view that all of them use. The rules for display are:

```
(("Assigned To" = [Me]) AND ("Completed" = "No") AND ("Severity Level" <> 1))
OR (("DM" = [Me]) AND ("Completed" = "No"))
OR (("Created By" = [Me]) AND ("Completed" = "No"))
```

That's all good and fine, and it works, but according to [this page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/manage-lists-and-libraries-with-many-items-HA010173667.aspx):

> Defining a view that uses an OR filter does not have any benefits of an indexed column.

I don't know of another way to do what I'm trying to do. Can anyone else help me here? Maybe I just need to do something with permissions. I am using a workflow for a change event to do some things. Maybe I could do something permissions related in there, with a lookup? Any ideas? I don't have a test environment, either, so I would like to make the change as simple as possible and easy to roll back if it doesn't work... I know, it is a bad situation.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: In a page, you could add the list 3 times and each view should show one line of your rules

Comment: That sounds like a great idea! I'll give it a shot and if it tests OK I'll format it and implement it this week. I'll post back with how it turns out.

Answer (score 0):

Make separate views and have SharePoint determine what view a user should have?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that you are hiting the view threshold and that is why you are asking your question. So I am wondering why you are not filtering first on Completed = No, and then on your 3 OR conditions, as that Completed = No is found in all 3. As per same link you quote :

> You can filter on many different columns, but it is important that the
>   first column that you use to filter the view has an index and that it
>   sufficiently reduces the total number of items returned.

Do you have more than 5 000 Non-completed items in your list?

Comment: That is what I thought at first, too. Apparently, though, once you introduce an "OR" into the mix, it all goes down the drain. The documentation isn't very clear about this and since the same thing is regurgitated on every blog in existence, Google isn't helpful in resolving this. I've tried many, many different configurations of the clauses and it just won't work. I'm going to try the custom page with multiple lists option as soon as I have time (shorthanded ATM). Thanks anyway, though.

Comment: Yes.. The list threshold logic is pretty much black magic to me, every time we do tests to understand why a specific view works / doesn't work we seem to find a new exception. :(